# How to solve this minimization calculus problem

Tags: calculus

A wire $24cm$ long is cut into two, and one part is bent into the shape of a circle, and the other into the shape of a square. How should it be cut if the sum of the areas of the circle and the square is to be a minimum? I know the answer is ${24\pi\over4+\pi}cm$ for the circle and ${96\over4+\pi}cm$ for the square but how to solve for it?

Comment: Have you started on this, other than looking up the answer? Hint: solution begins with  "Let $x$ be..."

Comment: i've had x=perimeter of square, then circumference = 24-x
then area for both

Comment: Good start. Please edit your question to say how far you've gotten with this.

Answer (score 2):

$x = $ perimeter of the square.
Then area is $\frac{x^2}{16}$ .

Radius of the circle is $\frac{24-x}{2\pi}$, so area is $\frac{(24-x)^2}{4\pi}$

Total area is $$\frac{x^2}{16} + \frac{(24-x)^2}{4\pi}$$

Derive this

$$\frac{x}{8} - \frac{(24-x)}{\pi}$$

It is zero in some point: that point is the minimum.